# How to add :autocmd to vim modeline?

Tags: vim, modeline

I am trying to add `:autocmd BufWrite * make` to modeline in vim, but it is not triggered. I see that the help says only `set <options>` can be used in modelines. Is there a way to achieve this effect, where I write a file to run `make`.

Answer (score 3):

Set your autocmd in your `~/.vimrc` with a pattern that will match your file name. I would also suggest using `augroup` so it can be made to be re-sourced.

```
augroup my_project
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWrite /project/*.c make
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h :aug
```